# Number Theory help

Tags: number-theory

This problem has been confusing me. I was wondering if i should do a proof of contradiction. Say that there is no prime then use quadratic reciprocity to show that there is a prime.

If n>2 show without using Bertrand's Postulate, the simpler result that there is a prime number p with n < p < n!. (Hint: Think about Euclid).

Answer (score 1):

The second question is immediate ($n!-1$ is not divisible by any number not exceeding $n$, so any prime divisor must be between $n$ and $n!$). The first question makes no sense. What does quadratic reciprocity mean if you don't know there is a prime? Are we allowed to prove that $2$ is a prime?

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for quadratic reciprocity. Start by assuming there's no such prime - that all primes have $p \leq n$ or $p \geq n!$. In particular, the only primes that divide the numbers $n < k < n!$ are the primes less than or equal to $n$. Assume you know all the primes less than or equal to $n$; multiply them all together like in Euclid's proof of the infinitude of primes; show that this is less than or equal to $n!$; **subtract** one, and find your contradiction.